# R repeated measures: lme specification for multiple replicates per subject and time point

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I have a repeated measures problem where my dataset has multiple replicates per per subject per time point. The number of repicates varies per subject. My objective is to use a mixed model to measure the effects of time in four week periods (Week), Type of call (Skill_Name), AgentLocation, CallerRegion, and LanguageCall on MeanCallTime.

AgentLocation does not change per agent but there are multiple replicates for each week depending on the type of call, caller region, and language of call. Due to these multiple replicates I've been unable to specify a covariance structure.

This is a sample of the structure of the data for a single subject:

```
DataFrame <- structure(list(AGENT_NUID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AgentLocation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "MAS", class = "factor"), CallerRegion = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("MAS", "NCAL", "SCAL"), class = "factor"), 
LanguageCall = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("English", 
"Spanish"), class = "factor"), Skill_name = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("CLAIMS", "CREDIT_CARD", 
"KPC_BILLING", "MAIN", "MEDICARE", "ORG"), class = "factor"), 
MeanCallTime = c(165L, 154L, 734L, 412L, 390L, 744L, 355L, 
264L, 401L, 682L, 245L, 251L, 335L, 103L, 656L, 542L, 350L, 
476L, 262L, 131L, 777L, 341L), Week = c(4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L)), .Names = c("AGENT_NUID", "AgentLocation", 
"CallerRegion", "LanguageCall", "Skill_name", "MeanCallTime", 
"Week"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

I want to allow intercepts and slopes to vary per subject (AGENT_NUID). On consultation, I have tried the following lme specification:

```
library(lnme)
Model<-lme(MeanCallTime~Week + AgentLocation + CallerRegion + LanguageCall + Skill_name,random=~Week|AGENT_NUID, correlation=corAR1(form=~Week|AGENT_NUID*AgentLocation*CallerRegion*LanguageCall*Skill_name),
    data = DataFrame,method="ML",na.action=na.omit)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Error in lme.formula(MeanCallTime ~ Week + AgentLocation + CallerRegion +  : 
incompatible formulas for groups in 'random' and 'correlation'
```

Is my error obvious to anyone? The corAR1 structure is to account for calls of the same CallerRegion, LanguageCall, and Skill_name handled by the same agent having that residual structure from one time period to the next.

Comment: Is the formula `lmer` or `lme` as you indicate? I can't reproduce your error message with `lmer`, although it tell me that it can't find the function "corAR1".

Comment: It's lme and this is just a sample of the actual dataset to show the structure of the data and the challenge posed by the replicates. I don't know how to post a large enough sample of the actual data for you to test, especially with all the fixed effects I'm trying to specify. I'm using lme because as I understand you can't specify cor structure with lmer, at least not easily. Does anything about my specification stand out as erroneous?

Comment: Is there a reason for the interactions in the formula for the AR(1) term? My recollection is that the RHS of the formula is 0 or more grouping factors, the combinations of which give the nesting within which the AR(p) is applied/estimated.

Comment: @AntoniParellada `lmer`/lme4 doesn't allow for correlation structures & the random effects go in the main formula so you won't be able to replicate the issue here in that software.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson I was advised that those interactions were the proper way to address the multiple replicates per time point. Another suggestion was to remove them only leaving the subject (AGENT_NUID) but I don't know if doing that create a problem with the residuals?

Comment: by replicates do you mean exact repeats of the predictor variable?  If so, why not just take the means of the repeated values (and use the `weights` argument to account for non-equal replication)?

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the suggestion. I am not familiar with the weights argument but I will look into how I might apply it properly with these data.